# xpath expression for numeric comparison

Tags: xpath, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script so can't change the source XHTML.

Given the following XHTML fragment:

```
<td>
    <span class="entry">Gender, Age:</span> Female, 42<br>
    <span class="entry">Country, Town:</span> United Kingdom, London 
    <span class="small09"></span>
</td>
```

is it possible to write an expression that can be evaluated using document.evaluate that will allow me to select all entries where the age is greater than, say, 40? I want something such as the following:

```
var matches = document.evaluate("//table[tbody/tr[2]/td[1][number(SOMEHOW 
  MATCH THE AGE PART) > 40]]", 
  document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
  null);
```

Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and very short, one-liner-XPath-expression solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use conditionals on text content, but you can filter the results with JavaScript.

Something like this should work:

```
var targetCells     = document.evaluate (
                        "//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]",
                        document,
                        null,
                        XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
                        null
                    );

for (var J = targetCells.snapshotLength - 1;  J >= 0;  --J)
{
    var thisCell    = targetCells.snapshotItem (J);

    //--- Get the age.  Key off (fe)male, {age in decimal years}<br> in the text of the table cell
    var ageTxt      = thisCell.textContent.match (/male[, ]+(\d+)/i);

    if (ageTxt  &&  ageTxt.length > 1)
    {
        var age     = parseInt (ageTxt[1]);
        if (age > 40)
        {
            //-----------------------
            //--- DO YOUR STUFF HERE.
            //-----------------------
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//table[tbody/tr[2]/td[1]
  [number(
    substring-after(normalize-space(span[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]),
                   ',')
          ) 
   > 
     40
    ] 
       ]
```

Comment: +1 Correct XPath answer. It would be hard doing something more general in XPath 1.0

Comment: Are you sure this works in Firefox (Greasemonkey)?   I get: `Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression." code: "51" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR)"`.

Comment: @Brock-Adams: Good catch -- thank you. I have fixed this issue (one ending `]` was missing.

Comment: Didn't get an alert on your comment; I guess "Brock-Adams" does not match "Brock Adams".  Anyway, [the solution now works](http://jsbin.com/apinu5/3) and taught me some more XPath. +1.

Comment: @Brock Adams: Glad my answer was useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you set age as an attribute you can access that value.

Something like

```
<Person Gender="F" Age="42" />
```

Comment: I'm writing a greasemonkey script and can't change the source HTML.